# Angular fileReplacements doesnt replace environments file

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a problem with replacing file contents of `environments.ts` file with prod or dev contents.

First of all, I have a script that reads .env files and adds values to `environments.dev` or `prod` file. So I expect when I run ng build --prod to replace `environments.ts` with `environments.prod`

Angular version: 11.0.9

angular.json

```
"architect": {
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
}
```

package.json

```
"start": "npm run config -- --environment=dev && ng serve",
"build": "npm run config -- --environment=prod && ng build --prod",
```

setenv.ts

```
const { writeFile } = require('fs');
const { argv } = require('yargs');

const ENV = 'local';

require('dotenv').config({ path: `.env.${ENV}` });

const environment = argv.environment;
const isProd = environment === 'prod';

const targetPath = `./src/environments/environment.${environment}.ts`;

const envConfigFile = `
export const environment = {
  production: ${isProd},
  host: '${process.env.HOST}',
};
`

writeFile(targetPath, envConfigFile, (err: any) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please  try

```
- - configuration=production
```

instead of

```
- - environment=prod`
```

Comment: still, the same file didn't change only options that I have is default ones 
`export const environment = {
  production: false,
};`

Comment: What's the version of. "@angular-devkit/build-angular"?

Comment: `@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.7`

Comment: Can you try with devkit version 0.900.7?

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with @angular-devkit/build-angular 0.1101.4 but not with 0.1100.7 -- downgrading fixed it for me.